# Mid point of two point where latitude and longitude given

Tags: java, math, dictionary

I am trying to find the midpoint of two points where latitude and longitude of those points are given. Using Haversine formula I can able to find the distance between between those points. I guess, I can also able find the midpoint by dividing the distance by 2. After that how can find the latitude and longitude of that midpoint. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was covered by Dr. Math.  [Latitude and Longitude of a Point Halfway between Two Points](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223101843/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51822.html)

Answer (score 0):

Find the Haversine distances of the latitudes and longitudes separately, and then apply the distance to each coordinate separately.

Comment: Can you please explain it more.