# How to get the radius given Min and Max Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: math, dictionary

Given coordinates:

```
min_lat=25.862491496700553
max_lat=26.358213103705367
min_lng=-80.790159828186
max_lng=-79.78628409576413
```

Is is possible to determine a radius?

Comment: You gave two points, what do you want to do with them.

Comment: Those coordinates are for SE and NW edges of the google maps square.

Comment: classic circle inscribed in a square problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Given [two geographic points] [i]s it possible to determine a radius?"

As asked, no.

A **[radius](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Radius.html)** is the distance from the center of a circle or sphere to its perimeter. It is used for 2D circles and 3D spheres.

That said, I suspect you may in fact being trying to ask a different question that can be answered.

- You may be asking for either the "[great circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)" between two points (each point with a latitude and longitude value);

I would suggest reading [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) by Chris Veness and the StackOverflow question here: "[How do I calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)"

If you need a unusually high degree of accuracy (far more than almost everyone using Google Earth needs) you can use the [Vincentry Formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) which takes into account an ellipsoidal Earth model, as the Earth is *not* a perfect sphere.

- Or you may of meant that you wish to find the mid-point of the four line segments along the perimeter of max and min latitude and longitude. e.g. (min_lat, min_lon), (min_lat, max_lon), (max_lat, min_lon), and (max_lat, max_lon), a less frequent request.

This covered in more detail in the StackOverflow question "[Mid point of two point where latitude and longitude given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650595/mid-point-of-two-point-where-latitude-and-longitude-given)."

Answer (score -2):

No. You could mark out that region on a billiard ball, or on Jupiter.